# Adding an UIElement to a Canvas (which is located in a UserControl) from another UserControl in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, canvas, user-controls, uielement

I have some UserControls in my project like **pnlCanvas** and **pnlTools**.

There are several buttons in **pnlTools** like "**Add Circle**", "**Add Rectangle**", "**Add Text**", ...

When the user clicks on one of the buttons, an element sould be added to the childrens of the Canvas (**cnvsObjects**) which is located in the **pnlCanvas**.

My ***MainWindow.xaml*** is like this:

```
<Window x:Class=...>
    <Grid>
        ...
            <local:pnlCanvas Grid.Column="2"/>
            <GridSplitter Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <local:pnlTools Grid.Column="4" />
        ...
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The ***pnlCanvas.xaml***:

```
<UserControl x:Class=...>
    <GroupBox>
        <GroupBox.Header...>
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <Canvas x:Name="cnvsObjects" Width="1920" Height=...>
            </Canvas>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </GroupBox>
</UserControl>
```

The ***pnlTools.xaml***:

```
<UserControl x:Class=...>
    <GroupBox>
        <GroupBox.Header...>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Add Text" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
            <Button Content="Add Rectangle"></Button>
            <Button Content="Add Line"></Button>
            ...
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>
</UserControl>
```

The ***pnlTools.xaml.cs***:

```
    ....
    public partial class pnlTools : UserControl
    {
        public pnlTools()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
            tb.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
            tb.Margin = new Thickness(10);
            tb.Text = "A Text as Test";
            cnvsObjects.Children.Add(tb); // Error!
        }
    }
}
```

As I've searched, I know in such cases I should use something like Dependency Properties. If it would have been a TextBlock, I could use Data Binding and a Dependency Property. But it is not a Property but a Method (Children.Add).

I'm new in WPF, so if All of things were in the *MainWindow.Xaml*, I had no problem. I have devided the *MainWindos.xaml* into some UserControls (nesting) to decrease the complexity and avoid a file to become huge. Did I choose **UserControl** for that purpose right? or should I use something else? What is the best way of doing that?

Sorry that this post became too long. I couldn't analyse other questions and answers related to this problem because they were so complex for me. Thanks.

Comment: The proper way would be to use a ListBox, which has the Canvas as ItemsPanel. Then bind data models to the ListBox and define DataTemplate to actually let the ListBox render the UIElements.

Comment: mmmmm, it is very complicated for a beginner like me. I will try to learn more about DataTemplate and ItemsPanel. It would be ausome if you would explain more or lead me through a good example like this.

Comment: How do you want to arrange the TextBlock elements? They are currently layered on top of each other. I assume this is not what you expect.

Comment: That's right, the purpose of this uncompleted example was to understand the main concept of how the data can be transformed between UserControls. Your first answer was about the method of implementation and was really great. I have learnt and coded exactly what you mentioned and that works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are executing the `Button.Click` event handlers in the wrong context. You would have to handle the `Button.Click` event in a context that has access to the `pnlCanvas` control, if this makes sense. Based on your posted example, the correct context would be the `MainWindow` as it hosts both `pnlCanvas` and `pnlTools`.

The recommended solution would be to change your overall design. This would involve the introduction of data model classes, that represent/hold the data for a `UIElement`, that you wish to add to the Canvas.
Such data would include the position on the canvas (x/y coordinates) and some data to display e.g., a text.
You would add those data models to a collection that serves as a binding source for a `ListBox`. The `Canvas` itself would be the panel of the `ListBox`, by assigning it to the `ListBox.ItemsPanel` property. You then define a `DataTemplate` for each data model type, where the `DataTemplate` contains the actual control you want to show. See [Microsoft Docs: Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) to learn about `DataTemplate`.

However, to fix your example you must first let the `PnlCanvas` control expose a public method that allows external controlslike the `MainWindow` to add elements to its internal `Canvas` (note that the proper naming for classes in C# would use *PascalCasing*.
For example `pnlTools` should be `PnlTools`. See [Microsoft Docs: Naming Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines#in-this-section). All provided code examples will use the official C# naming convention):

```cs
public void AddText(string text, Point position)
{
  var textBlock = new TextBlock() { Text = text };

  // Position the element on the Canvas
  Canvas.SetLeft(textBlock, position.X);
  Canvas.SetTop(textBlock, position.Y);

  this.cnvsObjects.Children.Add(textBlock);
}
```

Next, let `PnlCanvas` expose a set of routed commands, that the buttons in the `PnlTools` control can use. The `MainWindow` will then listen to those commands. See [Microsoft Docs: Commanding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/commanding-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

The complete `PnlCanvas` class will then look as follows (example only shows adding text to the `Canvas` or any other `Panel`):

**PnlCanvas.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class PnlCanvas : UserControl
{
  // TODO::Add commands to support other content
  public static RoutedCommand AddTextCommand { get; } = new RoutedCommand("AddTextCommand", typeof(PnlCanvas));

  public PnlCanvas()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  // TODO::Add methods to support other content
  public void AddText(string text, Point position)
  {
    var textBlock = new TextBlock() { Text = text };

    // Position the element on the Canvas
    Canvas.SetLeft(textBlock, position.X);
    Canvas.SetTop(textBlock, position.Y);

    this.cnvsObjects.Children.Add(textBlock);
  }
}
```

Then let `PnlTools` use the routed commands defined in `PnlCanvas`:

**PnlTools.xaml**

```xml
<UserControl>
  <StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Add Text" 
            Command="{x:Static local:PnlCanvas.AddTextCommand}" />
  </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Finally, let `MainWindow` execute the command:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    var addTextCommandBinding = new CommandBinding(PnlCanvas.AddTextCommand, ExecuteAddTextCommand, CanExecuteAddTextCommand);
    this.CommandBindings.Add(addCircleCommandBinding);
  }

  private void CanExecuteAddTextCommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    e.CanExecute = true;
  }

  private void ExecuteAddTextCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    var textPosition = new Point(100, 100);
    this.ElementHost.AddText("Some added text", textPosition);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The general idea behind using `UserControl` is two things:

1. Keeping the code more readable, organized and easier to maintain and scale in the long run.
2. Avoiding redundant code and repeated blocks of code. When the application uses similar UI patterns in different windows or pages, it is good practice to design a `UserControl` and use it anywhere it is needed.

Getting back to your main question, you can define a delegate/event in your PnlTools code-behind and register an event listener to it in the MainWindow code-behind.

**PnlTools.xaml.cs**:

```
public partial class PnlTools : UserControl
{
    public delegate void OnClickEventHandler();
    public event OnClickEventHandler OnClickEvent;

    public PnlTools()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnClickEvent();
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**:

```
<Window x:Class=...>
    <Grid>
        ...
            <local:PnlCanvas Grid.Column="2"/>
            <GridSplitter Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <local:PnlTools x:name="myPnlCanvas" Grid.Column="4" />
        ...
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pnlTools.OnClickEvent += PnlTools_OnClickEvent;
    }

    private void PnlTools_OnClickEvent()
    {
        TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
        tb.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
        tb.Margin = new Thickness(10);
        tb.Text = "A Text as Test";
        myPnlCanvas.cnvsObjects.Children.Add(tb);
    }
}
```